# Read Data from Datatable via searched Record in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, datatables

Hey i have an untyped Dataset with one Datatable and 9 Columns in it. Here are my DS DT and Columns

```
Dataset = ds_Databank_Skills
Datatable = dtab_Skills_Summary

Skill_ID = Int32 Unique and Primary Key
Skillname = String Unique
Lus = Boolen
Expert = Boolean
Categorie = String
Attribut = String
EP_Cost = Int16
Max_Level = Int16
Description = String
```

I would like to search my Datatable. Best way is **Skillname** *but i dont know if that works good (because the values have **spaces** and **""** and **-** in it. So perhabs i need to search by Primary Key so **Skill_ID**. All workd good, load it into my Datatable via xml File. But i cant find a way to search my Datatable and get the Values from the other Columns. This Values, i like to store in some Variables with same type (int32 int16 string and boolean) for further usage.

Perhabs someone like to help me here?

thank you so much for that.

I searched the web for some help, but most uses mysql or get all Data from Datatable. And iam sure there is an easy way to get that data.

Comment: The `Rows` property has a `Find` method to get a specific row by primary key or the `DataTable` itself has a `Select` method that allows you to use an arbitrary filter to get zero, one or more matching rows. Start by reading the relevant documentation, as you should already have done by starting with that for the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the DataTable.Select method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select)). There is an argument signature that allows you to pass in a String which represents a filter expression ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression#expression-syntax)).

Here is an example:

```vb
Dim searchTerm = "Some Value"
Dim expression = $"[Skillname] LIKE '*{searchTerm}*'"
Dim results = dtab_Skills_Summary.Select(expression)

For Each result In results
    Dim maxLevel = result.Item("Max_Level")
    Console.WriteLine("Max Level: {0}", maxLevel)
Next
```

Comment: thank you very much for that help, i will test that out, when iam back home and give here a anwser. Until than thanks again.

Comment: So iam at home and it works perfect, thank you so much for that help. Now i will read that documentation "jmcilhinney" mentioned. To understand that better.